# array without index from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I get this array from my php script:

```
[{"titre":"Titre","type":"title"},{"id":0,"type":"dual-img","src":  ["img\/sample_content\/sample-image-350x250.png","img\/sample_content\/sample-image-350x250.png"]},{"id":1,"text":"<p>Initial content<\/p>","type":"text"}]
```

But when i write this function, i got nothing.

alert(result[0]['titre'];

I don't know what to do to read this correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you have jQuery, use `parseJSON`

```
var test = <your incredible long result her>;
$.parseJSON(test);
alert(test[1].src);
```

alerts

> img/sample_content/sample-image-350x250.png,img/sample_content/sample-image-350x250.png

Comment: Thx, it's working.
result = $.parseJSON(result);
alert(result[1].src);

And i get: img/sample_content/sample-image-350x250.png,img/sample_content/sample-image-350x250.png

Answer (score 0):

This is `json` not the `array`

instead of using

```
alert(result[0]['titre']);
```

use

```
alert(result[0].titre);
```

Comment: Yes before but that you will have to parse this json data.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things here, and some more contextual code would help. But take a look at these:

- Are you trying to read the JSON in PHP or in JavaScript?
- If you are trying to read it in JavaScript, how are you passing the JSON from PHP to JavaScript?
- Did you check if it is being passed as a string or an array?

Comment: Hi,I passed the array by JSON

Answer (score -1):

javascript can't access a php variable like that. If you really need to do that then you can try

```
alert(<?php echo result[0]['titre']; ?>)
```

but even then there might be some issues with the scope of the variable etc. You might be better off using sessions if you absolutely need to do this.